# Using Auth0 in Flutter and With Google Gateway API

Tags: node.js, flutter, auth0

I am coding auth0 into my flutter application to login and register users. So far the Auth0 returns an access token and a id token. The ID token is a JWT with the basic user info like username email and profile picture etc, the issue being this flutter application communicates with an API that needs a JWT that I currently issue from a machine to machine API in Auth0. I need to make either the User ID JWT That the native app Auth0 application returns to the flutter app after successful sign in contain user scopes / permissions like `read:patients` `write:patients` etc or somehow call the M2M API and include a JWT Bearer token in the Payload of the regular access token. I have been trying to utilise Auth0 actions etc for this. I really hope someone can help.

I have tried using Auth0 actions and reading Auth0 documents and help of Google Gemini and Chat GPT to try pinpoint an alternative.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.